# mvc 3 default route not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have problems with default route for admin part.
I change folder structure from default, and now I have structure how at picture

**for admin**

[image: for admin]

**for modules**

[image: for modules]

I created two ViewEngine AdminViewEngine and CoreViewEngine

**AdminViewEngine**

```
public class AdminViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public AdminViewEngine()
    {
        AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Admin/Views/Shared/admin.cshtml" };

        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Admin/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml", "~/Admin/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml", "~/Admin/Menu/{0}.cshtml" };

        AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Admin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Admin/Menu/{0}.cshtml" };

        PartialViewLocationFormats = AreaPartialViewLocationFormats;
        ViewLocationFormats = AreaViewLocationFormats;
        MasterLocationFormats = AreaMasterLocationFormats;
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        return new RazorView(controllerContext, partialPath, null, false, FileExtensions);
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterPath))
        {
            masterPath = AreaMasterLocationFormats[0];
        }

        var view = new RazorView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath, true, FileExtensions);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**CoreViewEngine**

```
public class CoreViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    internal static readonly string Theme = SiteSettings.Instance.Theme;

    public CoreViewEngine()
    {
        string masterCatalog = string.Format("~/Themes/{0}/Views", Theme);
        string masterPath = string.Format("{0}/master.cshtml", masterCatalog);
        string partialThemesFolder = string.Format("~/Themes/{0}/Partials", Theme);

        MasterLocationFormats = new[] { masterPath };

        ViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Modules/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" };

        PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                "~/Blocks/{0}.cshtml", partialThemesFolder + "/{0}.cshtml", "~/Modules/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Modules/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
            };
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        return new RazorView(controllerContext, partialPath, null, false, FileExtensions, ViewPageActivator);
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterPath))
        {
            string masterCatalog = string.Format("~/Themes/{0}/Views", Theme);
            masterPath = string.Format("{0}/master.cshtml", masterCatalog);
        }

        var view = new RazorView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath, true, FileExtensions, ViewPageActivator);
        return view;
    }
}
```

And I have class for registered core and admin

```
public class ModulSetup : BaseModule
{
    public override void Setup()
    {
        this.SetupViewEngine();
        this.SetupControllers();
    }

    public override void SetupRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute("AdminRoot", "Admin", new { controller = "Site", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Site", action = "SiteSetting", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            string.Empty,
            new { controller = "News", action = "LastNews" });
    }

    protected void SetupViewEngine()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CoreViewEngine());

        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AdminViewEngine());
    }

    protected override void SetupControllers()
    {
        ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("SGN.Core.Admin.Controllers");
    }
}
```

Admin workin. But if I try go to default admin page _http://sitename/Admin/ I get 404
I try different variants for registered routes. But not help. I don't know what I must to do